# Is there a way to specify the proportions of an ImageView while using match constraint in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to place the following image at the top of my app.[image]

As you can see, it is cropped to have no extra white space. In my app, however, it appears to have different proportions, with extra white space at the top and bottom.

[image]

Here's the xml code for the ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/glyde"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/Glyde" />
```

Any idea what's wrong or how to fix it? I do not want to specify the exact values for width and height (in dps), as I want my app to work on several platforms.

Answer (score -1):

android:scaleType="fitXY"

You can add this property in xml file which will cause your image to fit according to the size of the image view widget it basically stretches the image to fill all the area of image view and then you can adjust the size of image view accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but I'm trying not to have to adjust the size manually (by specifying the number of pixels). I only want to use match_parent, match_constraint, and wrap_content.

Comment: Also, for further information, when I tried your advice, the image stayed the same size and shape, but the word stretched out vertically as you mentioned. I can't change the height without losing the cross-platform flexibility.